# How to I add translations for Month and Day in a date field?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am working on a Drupal 7 site that will be in English and Inuktitut. 
I have the i18n internationalization module installed. It does provide Inuktitut as a language option, but there are no available translations for Inuktitut.

I can see the options to localize the date format, but I need to be able to translate the months and days. How do I do this?

I'm looking for

Monday = naggajjau

Tuesday = aippiq

...

January = jaannuari

February = viivvuari

and so on.

Thank you

Comment: @samuelsov I went to admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string, checked all the boxes and refreshed strings

Then I went to admin/config/regional/translate/translate and I entered !month-name into the 'string contains field', I selected all languages, all text group and "search in both translated and untranslated'
I hit enter and no strings are found. 
I'm having trouble figuring out where to translate the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate everything in Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface (admin/config/regional/translate/translate)

Concerning dates, you usually need to translate the following strings :

- `!month-name |January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December` : you must keep `!month-name` and `|` in the translated string
- every string starting by `!long-month-name`
- `!day-name Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday`

And you should be good.

Even better, if you know several people interested in maintaining a language translation, you should go to https://www.drupal.org/node/807756 and reopen the issue. The goal is to have one place to improve and maintain the translation in https://localize.drupal.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can download translation from http://localize.drupal.org. I think the chance is relatively high that month names and weekdays are already translated.

Otherwise, go to Intraface Translation on you Drupal Site (admin/config/regional/translate/translate) and search for the month names and weekdays.

Comment: There is no translation available for Inuktitut. It is the language of Inuit (Eskimo) and there aren't many speakers. I tried admin/config/regional/translate/translate which will let me add a translation per node, but it is a bit onerous.
What I would like to do is have the names of the months translated where ever they are used. This works on a French/English site I worked on. I just have no clue how to tell drupal 'if it's the twelfth month, and the language is inuktitut, display tisipiri"