# Date format in another language

Tags: 8

I have a multilingual site. English and Dutch are the languages. I need to display date format in Dutch, ie  **I need to display a timestamp in Dutch(nl), as 16 oktober 2017.** Tried the below code and *format_date()*, but didn't do the trick.

```
$date = $node->getCreatedTime(); 
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, 'custom', 'd F Y', $timezone = NULL, $langcode = 'nl'); //not working for me

format_date($timestamp, $type = 'medium', $format = '', $timezone = NULL, $langcode = 'nl');
```

Above code returned date in "en" language. Am I missing something here.. Thanks..

Comment: Do you really need to do it with code? You can translate date formats  in `/admin/config/regional/date-time` and use translated date formats in any view mode / display setting

Comment: You need write something like: 

`$date = $node->getCreatedTime();
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, 'custom', 'd F Y', NULL,  'nl'); `

Answer (score 5):

You need write something like:

```
$date = $node->getCreatedTime(); 
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date, 'custom', 'd F Y', NULL, 'nl');
```

Answer (score 4):

The Drupal way of handling and translating Dates is through `Configuration > Regional and language > Date and time formats`, as Hudri mentioned in his comment.

### The same date and time Pattern between languages

What you should do depends on what pattern you want your date to be in English, if it should also be `'d F Y'` as in Dutch. If yes, then you should edit the relevant Date format through the interface. Content types use `Medium` as default for the “Submitted by” so edit that to keep things simple.

I expect you'll have the date and time related terms already translated into Dutch, so you'll get `oktober` and not `October` on the Dutch side.

### Different date and time Pattern between languages

If you want the Pattern of the same Date format to be different between laguages, for example you want English to be “10/16/2017” with Dutch “16 oktober 2017” you need to translate the Date format Pattern.

What is important to mention is that you need to have the **Configuration Translation** module enabled to be able to translate Date format Patterns. This will add the `Translate` link to the Operations button drop-down:

[image: translate_Dateandtime]

This enables you to have a different **Pattern** for different Languages under the same Date format.

Don't forget to Flush cache if you don't see the changes on existing content!

### Code manipulation

[The format_date() is Depricated](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/8.6.x), more info: [Date formats API changes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1876852), [public function DateFormatter::format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Datetime%21DateFormatter.php/function/DateFormatter%3A%3Aformat/8.6.x).

Answer (score -1):

You dont need custom code for it, every string can be translated via the translation interface.

Check this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/139407/3776